# node hapi rest put update joi validate only if present

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to validate my POST and PUT request in a Hapi Node server by using joi package.

Is it the right way ?

```
'use strict';

var Joi = require('joi'),
    Id = Joi.number().positive().required(),
    Firstname = Joi.string().min(3).max(15),
    Lastname = Joi.string().min(3).max(15),
    Email = Joi.string().email(),
    Username = Joi.string().min(3).max(15);


exports.create = {
    payload: {
        firstname: Firstname.required(),
        lastname: Lastname.required(),
        email: Email.required(),
                username: Username.required()
    }
};
exports.findById = {
    params: {
        userId: Id
    }
};
exports.update = {
    params: {
        userId: Id
    },
    payload:   Joi.object().keys({
        firstname: Firstname,
        lastname: Lastname,
        email: Email,
                username: Username
    }).or('firstname','lastname','email','username')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

of course you can modularise your validation check.

with your configuration you should be able use it just like this:

```
server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/find/{userId}',
  config: {
    validate: {
        findById  // this is defined by your code => exports.findById
    },
    handler: function (req, reply) {
        reply({
            receivedUserId: req.params.userId
        })
    }
  }
});
```